# What are possible ways of passing (additional) data to an event-handler in DOM / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

When running in developer mode on firefox, I get the error message, "Uncaught TypeError: EventTarget.addEventListener: Argument 2 is not an object."

What I'm trying to do is have the "playRound()" function run while passing the value "rock".

While trouble shooting, I put a console.log in the playRound() function and noticed that it runs it before even being told with the "click" action. The click doesn't even trigger anything.

Here is what I came up with so far ...

```js
function computerPlay () {
  let computerSelection = '';
  let randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  if (randomInt === 0) {
    computerSelection = 'Rock';
  } else if (randomInt === 1) {
    computerSelection = 'Paper';
  } else {
    computerSelection = 'Scissors';
  }
  return computerSelection;
}

function playRound (playerSelection) {
  let roundWinner = '';
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    roundWinner = "It's a tie!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Scissors'){
    roundWinner = "You win! Rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Rock' && computerSelection == 'Paper'){
    roundWinner = "You lose! Paper beats rock!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Rock'){
    roundWinner = "You win! Paper beats rock!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Paper' && computerSelection == 'Scissors'){
    roundWinner = "You lose! Scissors beats paper!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Paper'){
    roundWinner = "You win! Scissors beats paper!";
  } else if (playerSelection == 'Scissors' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    roundWinner = "You lose! Rock beats scissors!";
  }
  console.log('TEST');

  return roundWinner;
}

const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");

rock.addEventListener("click", playRound("rock"));
```

```html
<button id="rock" value="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper" value="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors" value="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: this looks like JavaScript, but you tagged Java....

Comment: You called `playRound("rock")` and gave its return value (`roundWinner`) as the event handler. This is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With event listeners, you need to pass the function in as the second parameter. At the moment, you are passing in the value returned by the method playRound's invocation.

Change the last line to:

`rock.addEventListener("click", () => playRound("rock"));` If you want to use an anonymous ES6 arrow function.

`rock.addEventListener("click", function() { return playRound("rock") });` If you would prefer the standard anonymous function syntax.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Of course one has to see the `"TEST"` log. Since `playRound` gets invoked while trying to add an event-listener to the `rock` element ... `rock.addEventListener("click", playRound("rock"))` ... the inner most function executes with `playRound("rock")`. Thus it will log, and it returns a string (the very `roundWinner`). This string value then will be added as the `rock` element's handler function via e.g. ... `rock.addEventListener("click", "It's a tie!")` ... which of cause immediately fails because `addEventListener`'s 2nd argument  needs to be a callable function.

A possible solution was to implement the `handleNextRound` event handler in a way that it reads a player's selection from one of the elements which was actively clicked on ...

```js
function computerPlay() {
  return [
    'rock',
    'paper',
    'scissors'
  ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function handleNextRound(evt) {
  const decisionMap = {
    rockscissors: "You win! Rock beats scissors!",
    rockpaper: "You lose! Paper beats rock!",
    paperrock: "You win! Paper beats rock!",
    paperscissors: "You lose! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorspaper: "You win! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorsrock: "You lose! Rock beats scissors!",
    scissorsscissors: "It's a tie!",
    paperpaper: "It's a tie!",
    rockrock: "It's a tie!"
  };
  const playerSelection = evt.currentTarget.value;
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();

  console.log('decision :', decisionMap[playerSelection + computerSelection]);

  // return decisionMap[playerSelection + computerSelection];
}

const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");

rock.addEventListener("click", handleNextRound);
paper.addEventListener("click", handleNextRound);
scissors.addEventListener("click", handleNextRound);
```

```html
<button id="rock" value="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper" value="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors" value="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

Another, in my opinion less favorable, approach was to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description) the value of a player's selection as argument (`[[BoundArguments]]`) to the handler function ...

```js
function computerPlay() {
  return [
    'rock',
    'paper',
    'scissors'
  ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function handleNextRoundWithBoundSelection(playerSelection, evt) {
  const decisionMap = {
    rockscissors: "You win! Rock beats scissors!",
    rockpaper: "You lose! Paper beats rock!",
    paperrock: "You win! Paper beats rock!",
    paperscissors: "You lose! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorspaper: "You win! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorsrock: "You lose! Rock beats scissors!",
    scissorsscissors: "It's a tie!",
    paperpaper: "It's a tie!",
    rockrock: "It's a tie!"
  };
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();

  console.log('(evt.currentTarget === this) ?', (evt.currentTarget === this));
  console.log('decision :', decisionMap[playerSelection + computerSelection]);
}

const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");

rock.addEventListener("click", handleNextRoundWithBoundSelection.bind(rock, 'rock'));
paper.addEventListener("click", handleNextRoundWithBoundSelection.bind(paper, 'paper'));
scissors.addEventListener("click", handleNextRoundWithBoundSelection.bind(scissors, 'scissors'));
```

```html
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
```

The third option already was suggested by others, ... provide the handler function as (anonymous) [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_function_expression), either as [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or classic ...

```js
function computerPlay() {
  return [
    'rock',
    'paper',
    'scissors'
  ][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function handleNextRound(playerSelection/*, evt*/) {
  const decisionMap = {
    rockscissors: "You win! Rock beats scissors!",
    rockpaper: "You lose! Paper beats rock!",
    paperrock: "You win! Paper beats rock!",
    paperscissors: "You lose! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorspaper: "You win! Scissors beats paper!",
    scissorsrock: "You lose! Rock beats scissors!",
    scissorsscissors: "It's a tie!",
    paperpaper: "It's a tie!",
    rockrock: "It's a tie!"
  };
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();

  // console.log('(evt.currentTarget.value === "") ?', (evt.currentTarget.value === ""));
  console.log('decision :', decisionMap[playerSelection + computerSelection]);
}

const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");

rock.addEventListener("click", function () { handleNextRound('rock'); });
paper.addEventListener("click", (/*evt*/) => handleNextRound('paper'/*, evt*/));
scissors.addEventListener("click", () => handleNextRound('scissors'));
```

```html
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
```